# How to prove that $\left(\ln(\ln(x)) \right)^2 \lt \ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How to prove that $\left(\ln(\ln(x)) \right)^2 \lt \ln(x)$ for sufficiently large $x$

This is what I did. Using L'Hopital's rule we have 
 $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\ln(\ln(x)) \right)^2 }{ \ln(x)}=0$$

So this implies that $\left(\ln(\ln(x)) \right)^2 \lt \ln(x)$

Is that enough?

Comment: Why is that? In the book it says that it's true

Comment: Yes, sorry. So it's enough :-)

Comment: That's pointed out not in the title but in the question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: In fact it's true for all $x\geq 2$ (even for smaller $x$)

Comment: @Surb: Whoops, I had momentarily confused $\ln \ln x$ for $\ln x$ when I tested that value ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. If you switch variable to $y=\ln x$, you want to prove that
$$ \ln(y)^2 < y $$
for sufficiently large $y$. Does that seem easier to prove?

If not, then switch variables once again to $z = \ln y$ and prove
$$ z^2 < e^z $$
for sufficiently large $z$.

Comment: $y$ doesn't need to be that large... $y\geq 0.5$ is enough...

Comment: Is my method right?

Comment: @J.Dane: Appealing to L'Hospital would also work, but I haven't checked the details. Immeditately it looks like it wold be more complicated to do it that way -- you'd need to apply the rule twice before you reach something that obviously converges.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Star from an inequality traditionally used in high-school to prove that $\;\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln x}x=0$:
$$\ln x<\sqrt x\quad\forall x>4,$$
and replace $x$ with $\ln x$: if $\ln x>4$, then
$$\ln(\ln x)<\sqrt{\mkern1mu\ln x\mathstrut}$$
Note that, as $x>4>\mathrm e$, both sides of the inequality are positive, hence you can square to obtain the required inequality for all $x>\mathrm e^4$.

Comment: Nice!, but I was thinking that from the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gomnypqsuy), it seems that $\ln(x) < \sqrt{x}  \forall x>0$ , so I was thinking about $x>4$ ? like why specific?

Comment: Computationally, it's simpler to prove (one uses a corollary of the *Mean  value theorem*, which says, roughly, that to comparetwo functions, you just have to compare initial values at some $x_0$ and compare the derivatives for $x>x_0$.

Comment: Nice, but I meant why you used $x>4$ and why not like for example $\forall x>2$ as $ln(2) - \sqrt{2} <0$ also ?

Comment: That was to ensure the same inequality on the derivatives: $\;\dfrac1x<\dfrac1{2\sqrt x}\iff x>4$.

Comment: Oh I am getting it, but still, I am still wondering what would go wrong if the proof was the same and I would just replace $\forall x>4$ with $\forall x >0$ and in the last line with $x> e^{0} = 1$? maybe it's trivial but still

Answer (score 0):

In the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(\ln(\ln(x)))^2}{\ln(x)}$$

take $\varepsilon = 1$ and have some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\forall x \geq M \ \ \left| \frac{(\ln(\ln(x)))^2}{\ln(x)} \right| < 1.$$

For large $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is no need for the absolute value, so we have $$\forall x \geq M \ \ \frac{(\ln(\ln(x)))^2}{\ln(x)} < 1,$$ which gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

$y:=\log (\log x)$, $x$ large ;

Take logs:

LHS:

$2\log (\log (\log x))=2 \log y$

RHS:

$\log (\log x)=y$

Need to show :

$2 \log y < y$ for sufficiently large $y$.

Used: $\log$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

For $x > 1$,
and for $0 < a < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(x)
&=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&<\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t^{1-a}}\\
&=\int_1^x t^{a-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{t^a}{a}|_1^x\\
&=\dfrac{x^a-1}{a}\\
&<\dfrac{x^a}{a}\\
\end{array}
$

If $a = \frac12$,
this gives
$\ln(x)
\lt 2x^{1/2}
$.

If $a = \frac14$,
this gives
$\ln(x)
\lt 4x^{1/4}
$
so
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^{1/2}}
\lt 4x^{-1/4}
$.
Therefore
$\dfrac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)^{1/2}}
\lt \dfrac{4}{\ln(x)^{1/4}}
$.

Answer (score 0):

For real $t > 0,$ we have
$$  t^{1/e} \geq \ln t,   $$
with equality only at $t = e^e.$ That is nice and specific, you should confirm that, any way you can. Draw some graphs, at least. Note that $e^e \approx 15.154$

Next, when $t > 1,$ we have $\sqrt t > t^{1/e}.$

Finally, take $t = \ln x$ for $x > 1$

The inequality you want is ALways true. not just for big numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should always remember the fundamental inequality satisfied by log function $$\log x\leq x-1,\,x>0\tag{1}$$ with equality happening only when $x=1$. Let $x>1$ and then replacing $x$ by $\sqrt[4]{x} $ we can see that $(1)$ implies $$\log x<4\sqrt[4]{x}$$ or $$\log^2x<16\sqrt{x}$$ and clearly $16\sqrt{x}<x$ if $x>256$. Thus we have $$\log^2x<x$$ if $x>256$. Replacing $x$ by $\log x$ we see that $$(\log\log x) ^2<\log x$$ if $x>e^{256}$.

The use of L'Hospital's Rule is fine if it is allowed by your professor (some people bar it for many exercises). On the other hand it is much simpler to prove the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\log x) ^a}{x^b}=0,\,a>0<b\tag{2}$$ using inequality $(1)$ and squeeze theorem.